# Discord.py: Are commands server only, or does it permanently edit the bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

If you had a command that, for example, changes a setting for responses that the bot gives. Lets say this setting is 'vulgarity', and you type in the command to turn off vulgar responses, would that turn off vulgar responses for the entire bot or just how the bot responds to that server? Example code below.

```
@client.command()
async def vulgarity(ctx, boolean):
    if boolean == 'On':
        # (insert code that enables vulgar responses)
    elif boolean == 'Off':
        # (insert code that disables vulgar responses)
```

Comment: With this code, yes. If you wanted it server only, you'd have to use a way to store data like a dictionnary, a json file or a database.

Comment: So, just to be clear, if someone in server A changes it to vulgar off, it also will effect server B unless I save their specific setting in a json file or a database?

Comment: yeah. with the commands library the bot applies to all channels it is mentioned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code directly effects the code's itself. So that means that it'd effect the bot. If you want it to effect only the guild that it's used, you have to store the data inside a file like json, yaml or txt. Or you can use a database but I wouldn't recommend it for this kind of simple data.

---

**Resources that you can use:**

- [Json Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- [Yaml Documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)
- [Sqlite Documentation](https://pysqlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlite3.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and supplying some resources.